# how to export selected column data to excel sheet

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, servlets

this is my jsp page. im using mysql database in this page im displaying the 
 complete data of table named strings1

```
<%@page import="com.connection.DbConnection"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script language="javascript">
function editRecord(id){
var f=document.form;
f.method="post";
f.action='edit.jsp?id='+id;
f.submit();
}
</script> </head> <body>
<form method="post" name="form">
    <table border="1">
        <%  Connection con = null;
            int sumcount = 0;
            Statement st;
            try { con = DbConnection.getConnection();
                String query = "select * from strings1";
                st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();  %>
        <tr>
            <th><%= rsmd.getColumnName(1) %></th>
            <th><%= rsmd.getColumnName(2) %>  <input type="button" name="edit" value="Download"
                style="background-color: green; font-weight: bold; color: white;">      
            </th>
            <th><%= rsmd.getColumnName(3) %> <input type="button" name="edit" value="Download"
                style="background-color: green; font-weight: bold; color: white;">      
            </th>
            <th><%= rsmd.getColumnName(4) %>   <input type="button" name="edit" value="Download"
                style="background-color: green; font-weight: bold; color: white;">      
            </th>
            <th><%= rsmd.getColumnName(5) %> <input type="button" name="edit" value="Download"
                style="background-color: green; font-weight: bold; color: white;">      
            </th>
            <th><%= rsmd.getColumnName(6) %>  <input type="button" name="edit" value="Download"
                style="background-color: green; font-weight: bold; color: white;">      
            </th>
            <th>Button</th>
        </tr>
        <% while (rs.next()) { %>
        <tr> <td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
             <td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
             <td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
             <td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
             <td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
             <td><%=rs.getString(6)%></td>
             <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit"
                style="background-color: green; font-weight: bold; color: white;"
                onclick="editRecord(<%=rs.getString(1)%>);"></td>
        </tr>
        <%  } %>
    <% } catch(Exception e) {  e.printStackTrace();   }   %>
   </table>
   </form> </body> </html>
```

what im thinking is if i click the download button only that entire column data should be export to excel sheet how can this will be achieved?

Comment: You can try to write a PHP  script, that queries your database and returns a .csv file.

Comment: Could you give more information on this question? Are you trying to provide download button for each column and then on click, do you want to download the corresponding data?

Comment: @BarathVutukuri yes exactly in each <th> tag there will be button like this  (<th>download</th>) if we click that button then entire that column data shoulb be download